# What's the best way to assign a value to variable that's "false" in perl

Tags: perl, variables, variable-assignment, default-value, var

I know a great thing about perl is that there's multiple ways of doing a lot of things, and I was wondering, What's the best (most efficient, most realiable, faster) way to assign a value to a variable that's false (0, empty string, undef, etc), some I know are:

```
if ( ! $x ) {
    $x = 1;
} 
# or $x = 1 if ( ! $x );

$x = $x || 1;

$x = 1 unless $x;

$x ||= 1;
```

Is there a better option?

Comment: How would you determine whether a given way is "better" than another?

Comment: Maybe being faster, or less likely to fail?

Comment: I don't see how any of those ways could fail, and there's probably nothing faster in pure Perl....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$x ||= $default;
```

is short, clear, fast and commonly used (i.e. readable).

Answer (score -3):

You may want to add the `//` and `//=` operators as well (checks for defined-ness). Having said that, if the difference in speed for these methods really matters to your program, you may want to move parts of your algorithm outside of perl and call it from perl instead (using perl as "glue").

Since the pedantic police is all over my ass in the comments, I took the time to benchmark it. Not the greatest benchmarking project in the world, but still I ran:

`time perl -e 'my $a; for (1..10000000) { $a ||= $_; }; print $a;'`

`time perl -e 'my $a; for (1..10000000) { $a //= $_; }; print $a;'`

On my system, the `//=` version is consistently 5-10% faster. YMMV.

Assuming the quotes around "false" in the original question meant "falsy" and not strictly false and further assuming that undef is a valid "false" value in this context, the undef version of the operator is some 5-10% faster.

On the assumption that the author of the question is looking for the fastest way to initialize an un-initialized variable, `//=` is probably faster based on the simple benchmarks I did, although my comments to optimizing in perl at this level still stands.

Comment: No, he may not. `0 // 1` returns 0.

Comment: As it should, since the scalar 0 is defined. What's your point?

Comment: `0` is false, and the OP asked to detect something that is false, so the solution should act when the initial value is `0`. `//` doesn't, so it's therefore wrong. That's his point.

Comment: He's asking about things that are "falsy". The hint is the quotes around false in the title, and he specifically mentions undef in his description as a kind of false. I disagree with your conclusion.

Comment: No, he wrote "false", and gave the examples `0, empty string, undef`. The word "falsy" is a fabrication from you, and your code does not deal with the examples, as already pointed out. • -1, not useful